# can we use jxl for google app engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine

Can we use JXL (Java Excel API) to generate Excel file in Google app engine application?

Also, how to generate Excel file in servlet for Google app engine application?

Comment: does jxl api is supported by google app engine or not?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can!

[Follow the tutorial to learn about JXL](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html).

To create a Workbook inside a servlet:

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    // Specifying in the response headers that a file is gonna be returned
    resp.setContentType("application/x-download");
    // Specifying the name of the file
    resq.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyName.xls");

    // Create the workbook with the output stream of the response
    WritableWorkbook jxlWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(resp.getOutputStream());
    // Do your stuff
    // ...

    // Finally close the stream
    resp.getOutputStream().close();
  }
```

Comment: yes ur right we can create ecxel with jxl api but why it does not works on google app engine application....

Comment: I'm using JXL in app engine without problems. Do you have an stack trace to show?

Comment: Raj, if Louismahou's answer helped, I suggest you upvote him. If it answered your question (and I think it did) please mark it as answered. That helps people know which questions have been answered. Thank you.